# How to show full height background image?

Tags: css, image, background

I have a photo type (not landscape) background image with 979px width by 1200px height. I would like to set it to float left and show 100% full image height fixed, without the need to scroll up/down (regardless of content length).

This is my CSS code, but it is not working:

```
img, media {
    max-width: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('../images/bg-image.jpg');
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

Comment: [**Like this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/4UmVg/)

Comment: Please define "not working".

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can do it with the code you have, you just need to ensure that `html` and `body` are set to 100% height.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/a7eGN/

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
} 

body {
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('http://www.canvaz.com/portrait/charcoal-1.jpg');
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I always wondered why this was working every now and then. Now I know :D

Comment: very nice ! Important fact to know or may be i have never expected this that is why i am somewhat astonish. that all the operations, you should do after setting the `background-image`. I was setting the `background-size` before and it was not working.

Answer (score 10):

```css
body{
    background-image: url("your_image_src");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
    height: 100vh;
}
```

it can cover full height and width as well

Comment: Good solution. The 100vh was fine.

Comment: this will ruin aspect ratio

Comment: `100vh` doesn't work for mobile devices

Answer (score 6):

CSS can do that with **background-size: cover;**

But to be more detailed and support more browsers...

Use aspect ratio like this:

```
 aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/A5ZNy/)

Answer (score 4):

```
 html, body {
    height:100%;
}

body { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (though it's for reactjs & tachyons used as inline CSS)

```
<div className="pa2 cf vh-100-ns" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${a6})`}}> 
........
</div>
```

This takes in css as **height: 100vh**