# display image full size css

Tags: html, css, image, blogs

I am trying to display this image in my blog full size : https://i.stack.imgur.com/02SU4.jpg

However it gets cropped ... i don't know why. I have tried rechecking the `.header` boundaries and I can't see where I would be limiting the size available for the image.

Here is the codepen for the site : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grLED

Please help

EDIT:

Just to clarify .. I would like my `.header` container to be big enough to house that image in full

EDIT 2:

so i just did this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJyFn to get the desired result ... can it be done without all those `<br>` ?

Comment: Add `background-size:cover;` to `.header`

Comment: Posible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901819/how-to-show-full-height-background-image)

Comment: use `background-repeat:no-repeat;` and `background-position:center center;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these properties to your `.header` class. But I am not sure if this'll work in old browsers.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

**Update**

If your height is less then the image height, you will loose dimension ratios. In this case your image will be stretched. You can define width and height like this `background-size: 300px 150px;` as described here.

Moreover you can use `cover` and `contain` options with `background-size` property. As your container height is less then the image you have to rely on this otherwise set width height screw background image.

For more reference please see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images).

Comment: it still doesn't show full picture .. here is the edited codepen with your suggestion : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Loect

Comment: which `height` are you referring to? My `height` for the `.header` section is set to `100%` ...

Comment: Suppose height of `header` in the page is `200px` and you image height is `1000px`. This is what I am saying that `.header` height is less than image height.

Comment: As you updated your question, how can you make header of page to full height of screen? If this is the case it should not be your header. Attach background to `body` or container `element`.

Comment: i don't want the header to be full height of the screen .. i just want it to be big enough to house that image in full ... isn't `.header` like any other container whose dimensions can be varied with contents in it

Comment: i am trying to make it look like this: http://bitofpixels.com/blog/mezzatheming-creating-mezzanine-themes-part-1-basehtml/

Comment: Then you should user `<img />` tag instead of background.

Comment: if I do that .. the text will be displayed below the image .. i want it to be overlayed over the image

Comment: Set position of text using `absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background-size.

```
/* Always cover the container (not a lot of support) */
background-size: cover;
```

Or

```
/* Fit width */
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Alternatively if you want it inside the div with absolutely no cropping you could set this to 'contain' or 'auto 100%' to fit the height.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: that one didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Do you need image to be displayed like in this link?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grLED

```
 body{
color: #202020; /*#3d3636    #fffaf0; #fdfdfd  8c8c8c*/
font-size:100%;
font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
line-height:1.4em;
min-height:100%;
/*padding-left: 5%;*/
 background: url('http://i.imgur.com/BruV8Hk.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
```

Comment: link you posted .. is the same one i posted in my original post .. if you have made any changes to file .. press 'fork' on top and post the new url

Comment: try using   'background-size:auto 100%;'

Answer (score 0):

I've made a small example for you, take a look at this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/609qtrLL/) it might help you out

There is an CSS3 property called

```
background-size:cover;
```

that will do the magic :)

Some more information can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: do you mind making changes to my code pen please to see if it works

Comment: ok you missed the point ... i don't want that image to be the background of the entire site ... i just want it to be the background of the `.header` container .. see edit to the original question

Comment: alight, sry for that. All you have to do is add: 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; to your .header class