# Force div to have the size of background image

Tags: html, css, overflow, background-image

When using a background image on a Div I am not able to display the full height of the image, neither using `height:auto;` or `height: 100%`. Why so?
How can I solve the problem?

I have created a JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2d0npz2v/5/

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.imageContainer2 {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/AWi7r5m.jpg");
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer2"></div>
```

***UPDATE***
Just for clarity, the image needs to be 100% width, and auto height (not cut at the bottom).
This example works but it's using the "content" property instead of the "background-image": https://jsfiddle.net/j47a6x7s/. I am looking for the same behaviour but without using content.

Comment: You have to assign div height and width.

Comment: Works for me, you just forgot to set the ehight inn your fiddle.

Comment: @AlexG, no, the image is not fully displayed, some part of the image is cut at the bottom.

Comment: your fiddle do not show image at all? guys do tell you ok that you need to put some height on your container, right?

Comment: @oserk I have updated the link because for some reasons it was not showing the image, I don't know why

Comment: do you need this? https://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/kkozs6ae/1/

Comment: no @oserk, image needs to be 100% width.

Comment: so that means that image would be stratched?

Comment: @oserk no no, you should be able to scroll to see the full height of the image. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/j47a6x7s/ but I don't want to use the property "content", I want to use the background-image property.

Comment: god damn,, that's hard..but would like to know the answer :)

Comment: @oserk hahah! You understand how I feel....!! Thanks for trying and let's hope someone can find an answer!!

Comment: @MaRco85, there will always be one side clipped, unless you stretch the image. Which you can achive with `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Thanks @AlexG, I know about the cover option but that is not showing the full image.. as I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the reason why this is?

In your working example you use content. A content has it's own height and uses up space, which the other elements on the page have to respect.

With the `background-image` solution, you use a background, which does not use space. The `.imageContainer2` element can not know about the height of the background-image AND adapt itself to it.

This very problem was addressed here: [How to get div height to auto-adjust to background size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size)
Just check, if the workaround is suitable for you

Comment: Many thanks @HerrSerker, You are right and the question is actually explaining the same problem.

Comment: If you are in charge of the HTML Code, you could set the necessary CSS like `background-image`, `padding-bottom` as inline `<style>` for example. In that case I recommend using an attribute id on the HTML element, which is unique for __exactly__ that element. Something like `imagecontainer2-1234` where 1234 is a unique of that element. A different image container could have the id `imagecontainer2-2345` and so on.

Comment: yes, definitely. thanks for the details! @HerrSerker

Answer (score 2):

If the image(s) you want to display in the background property always has the same aspect ratio, you can use one of the techniques [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1495407/1811992) to make the div keep the same aspect ratio as the image according to the width.

With your example it would look like this :

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.imageContainer2 {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/AWi7r5m.jpg");
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  padding-bottom:178%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer2"></div>
```

*Note that I don't know what you are trying to achieve exaclty. Using this method to display an image probably isn't semanticaly correct depending on the context.*

Comment: Thanks web-tiki. I have chosen HerrSerker answer becuse the link he posted is exactly explaining my problem but your answer is also good. What I am trying to achieve is: not use img src, use background-image so I can replace the image sources using CSS media query, but I experienced issues with the height.. and also compatibility with different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var bgImg = new Image();
  bgImg.src = $('.test').css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
  bgImg.onload = function() {
  $('.test').css({'height':this.height,'width':this.width});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" style="background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/36487/above-adventure-aerial-air.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');">

</div>
```

Hope this exactly solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving these three to your `.imageContainer2`:

```
.imageContainer2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jsse9yL3/**

Comment: height: 100%; is enough rt?

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS `position` is needed buddy. Coz there's nothing inside the `div`.

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar but no this doesn't work, I cannot scroll to see the full height of the image :-/

Comment: @MaRco85 So if you wanna have the height of the image, then you need to set the `height:` as the image's height and not the `100%`.

Comment: Well, I really believe there is a more generic solution without having to specific the size of it, that's exactly what I was try to find out

Comment: @MaRco85 I had come across this. Well, there's no way to detect the height of the image when used using `url()`. Sorry! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar, so why when using "content:url("image.jpg");" the height is detected?

Comment: @MaRco85 Whatever you do, you can set the height and width relative to boundaries only. In this case, it is the window height. So if you wanna make it to work with the CSS, CSS doesn't have the power to detect the size of the image.

Comment: I am grateful for your help but I hope someone can give a solution. If not, your answer will be the accepted one :-)

Comment: @MaRco85 Thanks buddy. Let's wait and see... I don't think it is possible, coz I am working on HTML / CSS for the past 8 years and I cannot figure this thing out. `:)`

Comment: @MaRco85 Do you still wanna wait?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes, I will also open a bounty for this question, there seems to be many options but I cannot achieve what I want to have, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901819/how-to-show-full-height-background-image

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an **IMG** for do that. Why you are insisting using CSS?

Example:

```css
.container img
{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.wallpaperawesome.com/wallpapers-awesome/wallpapers-full-hd-1080-x-1920-smatphone-htc-one-lumia-1520-lg-g2-galaxy-s4-s5-awesome/wallpaper-full-hd-1080-x-1920-smartphone-vertical-stiped-nebula.jpg"/>
</div>
```

You can't calculate the **background-image** height with a CSS rule and then make the DIV height's equal.
The closest solution for your problem is using a **background-cover** with all the related "issues".

**UPDATE**

Another CSS solution could be the padding-trick way, as follows:

```css
.container
{
    background-image: url('http://www.wallpaperawesome.com/wallpapers-awesome/wallpapers-full-hd-1080-x-1920-smatphone-htc-one-lumia-1520-lg-g2-galaxy-s4-s5-awesome/wallpaper-full-hd-1080-x-1920-smartphone-vertical-stiped-nebula.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    width: 100%;
    height: 0;

    padding-top: 177.77%; /* img-height / img-width * container-width (1920 / 1080 * 100) */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
</div>
```

I suggest anyway to use the first solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dario, but If I am insisting with CSS there is a reason. I cannot set a src for the image (solution1) as I need to replace the image source using media css queries (and load different images for mobile/tablet etc). solution2 is also not good because it's cropping part of image and it is not even the same result as using a simple tag <img> with the src as in solution1.

Comment: You are welcome Marco but there is no other solution unfortunately. You have to build media query classes and insert multiple different IMGs that will be hidden depending on device resolution, I can provide to you an example if you need. By the way, the second solution isn't cropping anything, the result is identical to the first solution.

Comment: You are actually right Dario, I am sorry I didn't notice the padding-top attribute in the second solution (which is probably the most correct one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size). However I cannot use multiple different images otherwise they will all get downloaded (even if they are hidden). Thank you anyway for your answer and patience!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.imageContainer2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
}
```