# How to make background image of full height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> 

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
             <div class="for-video-background" style="background-image: url('./assets/images/back-video.png');">
               <a href="#">
                  <img src="./assets/images/play-icon.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" style="width: 5rem;">
               </a>
             </div>
          </div>
```

I want the background image to take full height and the sub-image must align the center of the background image.
And at last it must be responsive.

Comment: can you use online images instead of local ones to make your question reproducable

Comment: Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901819/how-to-show-full-height-background-image) will help you!

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "height:100vh"

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
  <div class="for-video-background" style="background-image: url('./assets/images/back-video.png');">
     <a href="#">
        <img src="./assets/images/play-icon.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" style="width: 5rem;height: 100vh">
     </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no i want the for-video-background section background to take full height

Answer (score 0):

Use `width:100vh` to make full height and use `left` and `right` make the `image` become center.

Use the `background-size: cover` to resize the background image to cover the entire container.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <div class="for-video-background" >
               <a href="#">
                  <img src="./assets/images/play-icon.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" >
               </a>
             </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
img{
    width:5rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 47.5%;
    top: 47.5%;

}
.for-video-background{
    height: 100vh;
     background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('./assets/images/back-video.png')
}
```